# Possible to create absolute link for local HTML file

Tags: html, hyperlink, path, local, absolute

Is this possible. From what I understand, absolute paths are most commonly used with links to a website. I am not using a web server, my HTML file is local and needs to be linked to another HTML file using an absolute link. These were my directions and any clarity is much appreciated, as I don't fully understand how I would do this yet. Thanks.

Directions:

- Create a navigation (nav) menu pointing to the two HTML pages in the menu directory
  -The link to the menu page should be relative and point to the entrees section
  -The link to the health-warning page should be absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on where the html file lives. If you're doing this locally then it'll depend on where the html file you're referencing is on your computer. If you're on windows that could be `C:\Users\yourusername\projects\whateverfile.html` while on Mac or Linux it would be `file:///home/yourusername/projects/whateverfile.html`. Those are absolute paths. A relative path is where the file is in relation to the html you're adding the link to. An example for your assignment could look like.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="./menu.html">Menu Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="file:///home/yourusername/projects/menu-project/health-warning.html">Health Warning</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: yes, thank you. Is there a way you could find it using the command line?

Comment: Depends on your system. Are you on Linux or a Mac? If so use `find <directory> -iname <filename>`. So in the example above it would be `find /home/yourusername -iname health-warning.html`. On a Windows machine try `cd\` followed by `dir /s *health-warning.html`

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. For a local absolute link, you would expect to see your absolute link start with `C://` if you are on a Windows machine.